# How to create case-sensitive message filters?

Tags: thunderbird

The [message filters](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/organize-your-messages-using-filters) certainly are case-insensitive by default — this obviously limits their potential to some degree.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the Thunderbird add-on
[Expression-Search-NG](https://github.com/opto/Expression-Search-NG),
which adds sophisticated search operators.

Some of the added operators are case sensitive and some are
case insensitive. As a rule, all operators that accept regex are
case sensitive unless you have `//i`.

A small danger-sign is that the developer has not answered issues for
the last few months, but if it works...)